# How can ı write filter insted of splice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to doing form project with react. I have table inside of my project and my table has delete button. So ı wrote code for delete table values but my teacher said write your code with filter insted of splice. Can you help me for how can ı write this code?

```
const ReadRow = ({ addForm }) => {
  const { addFormData, setAddFormData } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const handleDeleteClick = (addFormId) => {
    const newAddFormData = [...addFormData];
   
     newAddFormData.splice(addFormId, 1);
    
    setAddFormData(newAddFormData);
};
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I could provide the answer but as Reyno mentioned try figure it out yourself. As a little hint check out https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter . You have to filter for everything that does not match the id you are passing towards the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array by the index

```js
const ReadRow = ({
  addForm
}) => {
  const {
    addFormData,
    setAddFormData
  } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const handleDeleteClick = (addFormId) => {
    const newAddFormData = addFormData.filter((_, index) =>
      index !== addFormId
    )

    setAddFormData(newAddFormData);
  };
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to filter by index? We don't even know to input so how can we know the output?

Comment: `newAddFormData.splice(addFormId, 1)` this code is remove element in index `addFormId` until `1` inside `newAddFormData` it's same as remove `addFormId` index. using filter you can check is the index of the current iteration is the same with `addFormId` if it same we need to remove it. to remove it just return `false` instead of `true`